# MySQL query with calculation from two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 4.2.

I have 2 tables:

- `tbl_User` stores USERID and REGCODE. REGCODE is the code user used for signup the service.
- `tbl_Message` stores messages posted by each of those users.

I need to query all users in tbl_User for the corresponding REGCODE to get total.
Then, I would like to know is how many of these users have at least one entry in tbl_Message where their USERID matches up with AUTHORID.
The last row is the % of user has post.

My goal is to calculate the percentage from two tables at last row, but I am not sure how to join tables in query to get the correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Tables chart:
http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/6105/tablep.png

Here is the query I am using:

```
Select 'Percentage',
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9001 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9001 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9002 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9002 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9003 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9003 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9004 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9004 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9005 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9005 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9006 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9006 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9007 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9007 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0,
  Sum(Case
    When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9008 And
   tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID Then 1 Else 0
  End) / Sum(Case When tbl_User.REGCODE = 9008 Then 1 Else 0 End) * 100.0
From tbl_User 
left Join tbl_Message
tbl_Message ON tbl_User.USERID = tbl_Message.AUTHORID 
Where tbl_Message.AUTHORID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can you add the structures of the two tables please? That will help

Comment: It would help if you explained (in words) what you are trying to do -- e.g. "the percentage of messages in each user's inbox that they are the author of"?

Comment: http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/6105/tablep.png

Comment: I have 2 tables:
tbl_User stores USERID and REGCODE. REGCODE is the code user used for signup the service.

tbl_Message stores messages posted by each of those users. 

I need to query all users in tbl_User for the corresponding REGCODE to get total.
Then, I would like to know is how many of these users have at least one entry in tbl_Message where their USERID matches up with AUTHORID.
The last row is the % of user has post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT REGCODE,
       COUNT(tbl_User.USERID) as totalUsers, 
       COUNT(tbl_Message.MESSAGEID) as usersWhoPosted 
       COUNT(tbl_Message.MESSAGEID)/COUNT(tbl_User.USERID)*100 As Percent
FROM tbl_User 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Message ON tbl_User.USERID=tbl_Message.AUTHORID 
WHERE REGCODE BETWEEN 9001 AND 9008
GROUP BY REGCODE
```

This will give you something like (based on your picture):

```
REGCODE   totalUsers  usersWhoPosted  Percent
9001      763         233             30.5374
...   
9008      345         235             68.1159
```

It's much easier to have the `REGCODE` in the rows than the columns. Otherwise you're stuck with writing a huge unwieldy query for each `REGCODE` you're interested in like you are currently using.

If you really must have the table transposed (ie swap rows/columns), do it programmatically (eg in PHP if that's what you're using with MySQL).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I'm looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have a question regarding to the number of totalUsers. The COUNT(tbl_User.USERID) as totalUsers is affected by LEFT JOIN tbl_Message ON tbl_User.USERID=tbl_Message.AUTHORID. If I only COUNT(tbl_User.USERID), the number is different from use the LEFT JOIN. How can I overcome this issue? Thanks.

Comment: ahh, you're right - I have to skip this for the next day or so because I'm busy, but I'll have a look at it after (or someone else is welcome to!)

Comment: no worries..I know you are busy. Thanks for all your helps. Another nice guy helped me solve this issue.